# How to locate the coordinate of the center of a rectangle to draw a concentric circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to draw a rectangle with a golden ratio; to manually locate its center, and draw a concentric circle.

Is there a better automated way to locate the coordinate of the center of a rectangle!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right]
\draw[thin, blue] (0,0) node(dl){} --++(0:3.236) node(dr){}  --++(90:1.618) node(ur){}  --++(180:3.236) node(ul){} --++(-90:1.618);
\draw[thin, green](dl.center)--(ur.center) (dr.center)--(ul.center);
\node at (1.618,.809) (x){.};
\draw [thin, red] (x) circle (.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a node or coordinate in the middle of a diagonal:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin, blue] (0,0) node(dl){}
  --++ (0:3.236) node(dr){}
  --++ (90:1.618) node(ur){}
  --++ (180:3.236) node(ul){}
  -- cycle
;
\path[draw, thin, green]
  (dl.center)--(ur.center)
  (dr.center)--(ul.center) node[midway,black](x){.}
;

\draw [thin, red] (x.center) circle [radius=.6];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]